# MemoryError in python 3.6

Tags: python, matplotlib, pycharm, cluster-analysis, networkx

I Run this code and get the error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>    File "C:/Users/asus/PycharmProjects/Refah_New/Clustering.py", line 177, in 
>      G.add_edge(personid[l], personid[t], weight=x, edge_color='r')
>    File "C:\Users\asus\PycharmProjects\Refah_New\NewInterpretor\lib\site->packages\networkx\classes\graph.py", line 891, in add_edge
>      self._adj[u][v] = datadict
>   MemoryError

I'm Reading a CSV file with 50000 personid and dahak and store these in two lists. then, i wanna to create a network with personid as nodes and a weight that calculates from dahak as edges.

```
import csv
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

myfile = r'C:\Users\asus\Downloads\income.csv'

personid = list()
dahak = list()

with open(myfile, mode='r') as infile:
    reader = csv.reader(infile)
    for row in reader:
        personid.append(int(row[0]))
        dahak.append(int(row[1]))

t=len(dahak)
l=len(dahak)
graphlist=list()
G = nx.Graph()

for l in range(l):
    print("counter: ", counter)
    for t in range(t):
        if l!=t:
            if dahak[l]==dahak[t]:
                G.add_edge(personid[t],personid[l],weight=1,edge_color='b')
            elif dahak[l] != dahak[t]:
                x = 1 - (abs(dahak[l] - dahak[t]) / 10)
                if x >= 0.3:
                    G.add_edge(personid[l], personid[t], weight=x, edge_color='r')

pos = nx.spring_layout(G)
nx.draw_networkx_labels(G,pos)
nx.draw(G)
plt.show()
```

Comment: what version of networkx do you have? you can see that with `print(nx.__version__)`

Comment: @MaxPower version of networkx is 2.4

Comment: I don't know about the memory error, but here's a probable bug in your code: `for l in range(l): ...
    for t in range(t):`

Just set `l` to be something and `t` to be something and run this, printing out `l` and `t` each time.